# Optimize a simple and quick python script for transposing a .csv file

Tags: python, performance, regex, csv, pandas

I need to transpose the following file output1.csv, which is is a result from a quantum chemistry calculation into a single colum efficiently:

```
 Frequencies --    18.8210                44.7624                46.9673
 Frequencies --    66.6706               102.0432               112.4930
 Frequencies --   124.4601               138.4393               180.1404
 Frequencies --   230.0306               240.4389               258.2459
 Frequencies --   282.7781               340.8302               357.7789
 Frequencies --   378.9043               384.1284               401.4285
 Frequencies --   418.0523               444.2264               447.6885
 Frequencies --   473.2391               501.0937               518.9083
 Frequencies --   559.5925               609.9256               623.7729
 Frequencies --   657.4144               672.5480               728.2009
 Frequencies --   740.5035               750.3238               757.2199
 Frequencies --   774.6343               806.7750               815.9990
 Frequencies --   839.3050               858.0716               876.1641
 Frequencies --   888.6654               942.2963               965.7888
 Frequencies --   987.3819               994.7388              1020.8724
 Frequencies --  1025.0426              1045.5129              1059.0966
 Frequencies --  1076.5127              1143.1178              1155.4200
 Frequencies --  1208.6790              1219.7513              1244.7080
 Frequencies --  1265.6108              1287.8830              1300.0463
 Frequencies --  1325.0427              1339.0678              1353.0061
 Frequencies --  1369.0614              1408.5258              1433.0543
 Frequencies --  1452.4148              1454.6319              1500.4304
 Frequencies --  1511.2305              1517.2562              1552.9189
 Frequencies --  1560.5313              1636.2290              1640.1732
 Frequencies --  1664.8747              1681.5566              1703.2026
 Frequencies --  1770.2627              3058.4143              3122.3743
 Frequencies --  3147.1828              3192.5897              3199.1398
 Frequencies --  3211.0676              3222.0033              3236.3394
 Frequencies --  3262.2119              3556.7997              3862.4791
```

To achieve that I wrote this code:

```
import os
import csv
import re
import sys
import pandas as pd

inputfile = open('output1.csv', 'r')
reader = csv.reader(inputfile)

outputfile = open('output1_f.csv', 'a')
writer = csv.writer(outputfile)

with open('output1_f.csv', 'w') as file:
    file.write('Frequencies,Frequencies,Frequencies\n')
for row in reader:   
    row = [re.sub(' +', ',', item) for item in row]
    row = [re.sub(',Frequencies,--,', '', item) for item in row]               
#    row = map(str.strip, row)
    writer.writerow(row)

inputfile.close()
outputfile.close()
```

I added the code as comment in order to delete the first and last character " from every line in the output1_f.csv file. However it does not work out.

```
 row = map(str.strip, row)
```

I found the line.replace solution which creates a second output1_2f.csv file.

```
inputfile = open('output1_f.csv', 'r')
outputfile = open('output1_2f.csv', 'w')
for line in inputfile:
    line = line.replace('"', '')
    outputfile.write(line)

inputfile.close()
outputfile.close()
```

The following transpose part works only if the character " is removed and this is the reason that I need to delete the " character efficiently code instead of line.replace.

```
ifile  = open('output1_2f.csv', "rb")
reader = csv.reader(ifile)

with open('output1_transp.csv', 'w') as out:
    rownum = 0
    for row in reader:
    # Save header row.
        if rownum == 0:
            header = row
        else:
            colnum = 0
            for col in row:
                out.write( '%s\n' % (col))
                colnum += 1

        rownum += 1

ifile.close()
```

I would be grateful if you could propose me any idea to shorten the code and make it more efficient and easier to use. Thank you developers for your time!!!

Comment: It's not clear what the result is intended to be.  Is it a file with a single column of frequencies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe there is a **much** simpler way of doing this.

If I correctly understand the problem, the idea is to produce a single column of frequencies.

```
with open('input.txt', 'r') as infile, open('out.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    print >> outfile, "Frequency"
    for line in infile:
        for freq in line.split()[2:]:
            print >> outfile, freq
```

This iterates over each line in the input file.  It uses `split` to eliminate whitespace and to split each line into fields.  It then discards the first two, which are assumed to be "Frequencies" and "--" and writes the remaining fields to the output file.

Comment: Downvoter: could you explain?  How could this answer be improved?

Comment: @Edward I'm not the downvoter, but `print >> outfile, "Frequency"` is only erroring for me. And may explain the downvote.

Comment: @JoeWallis Could it be version difference? The question itself isn't tagged with a specific version.

Comment: @Mast Yes, `print >>stream, ...` is explicitly Python 2, in Python 3 you use `print(..., file=stream)` instead.

Comment: @MathiasEttinger @Mast I copied the `open` without the `'w'` flag. Silly me ):

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding what you want, and you are already importing pandas, this can be done very easily:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('output1.csv', header=None, delim_whitespace=True)
df = df.iloc[:, 2:].stack().reset_index(drop=True).to_frame()
df.insert(0, -1, '--')
df.insert(0, -2, 'Frequencies')
df.to_csv('output1_f.csv', sep=' ', mode='a', index=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, header=None)
```

And the result:

```
Frequencies -- 18.821
Frequencies -- 44.7624
Frequencies -- 46.9673
Frequencies -- 66.6706
Frequencies -- 102.0432
Frequencies -- 112.493
Frequencies -- 124.4601
Frequencies -- 138.4393
Frequencies -- 180.1404
Frequencies -- 230.0306
Frequencies -- 240.4389
Frequencies -- 258.2459
Frequencies -- 282.7781
Frequencies -- 340.8302
Frequencies -- 357.7789
Frequencies -- 378.9043
Frequencies -- 384.1284
Frequencies -- 401.4285
Frequencies -- 418.0523
Frequencies -- 444.2264
Frequencies -- 447.6885
Frequencies -- 473.2391
Frequencies -- 501.0937
Frequencies -- 518.9083
Frequencies -- 559.5925
Frequencies -- 609.9256
Frequencies -- 623.7729
Frequencies -- 657.4144
Frequencies -- 672.548
Frequencies -- 728.2009
Frequencies -- 740.5035
Frequencies -- 750.3238
Frequencies -- 757.2199
Frequencies -- 774.6343
Frequencies -- 806.775
Frequencies -- 815.999
Frequencies -- 839.305
Frequencies -- 858.0716
Frequencies -- 876.1641
Frequencies -- 888.6654
Frequencies -- 942.2963
Frequencies -- 965.7888
Frequencies -- 987.3819
Frequencies -- 994.7388
Frequencies -- 1020.8724
Frequencies -- 1025.0426
Frequencies -- 1045.5129
Frequencies -- 1059.0966
Frequencies -- 1076.5127
Frequencies -- 1143.1178
Frequencies -- 1155.42
Frequencies -- 1208.679
Frequencies -- 1219.7513
Frequencies -- 1244.708
Frequencies -- 1265.6108
Frequencies -- 1287.883
Frequencies -- 1300.0463
Frequencies -- 1325.0427
Frequencies -- 1339.0678
Frequencies -- 1353.0061
Frequencies -- 1369.0614
Frequencies -- 1408.5258
Frequencies -- 1433.0543
Frequencies -- 1452.4148
Frequencies -- 1454.6319
Frequencies -- 1500.4304
Frequencies -- 1511.2305
Frequencies -- 1517.2562
Frequencies -- 1552.9189
Frequencies -- 1560.5313
Frequencies -- 1636.229
Frequencies -- 1640.1732
Frequencies -- 1664.8747
Frequencies -- 1681.5566
Frequencies -- 1703.2026
Frequencies -- 1770.2627
Frequencies -- 3058.4143
Frequencies -- 3122.3743
Frequencies -- 3147.1828
Frequencies -- 3192.5897
Frequencies -- 3199.1398
Frequencies -- 3211.0676
Frequencies -- 3222.0033
Frequencies -- 3236.3394
Frequencies -- 3262.2119
Frequencies -- 3556.7997
Frequencies -- 3862.4791
```